# Instead of saving inside array, data is getting stored inside new record

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am uploading images using ***MEAN*** stack and **Multer** module.
I am able to retrieve images from the angular, and can even post image-paths to Mongoose collection.
The problem is I am expecting an array of images but while posting to mongoose, it's storing each image as a new record. 


**Image schema**

```
var imageSchema=new Schema({
    productId:{type: String,required: false},
    imagePaths: [{type: String, required: false}]
});
```

**POST API**

```
router.post('/upload', upload.any(), function(req , res){
  console.log('Executing Upload API..');
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    var images = req.files;

req.files.forEach(function(file){
      var filename = (new Date()).valueOf() + '-' + file.originalname;
      fs.rename(file.path,'public/images/'+ filename, function(err){
       // if (err) throw err;
        //Save to mongoose

        var image = new Image({
          productId: 1007,
          imagePaths: filename
        });
        image.save(function(err, result){
          if(err) throw err;
            res.json(result);
        });
        console.log('FileName :' + filename);

      });
    });
});
```

**Collection saved** 
*If I post 2 images, it's getting stored as shown below, but I want both the images to be sotred in same record, i.e inside `imagePaths:`.*

**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59abab004783d90bccb4a723"),
        "productId" : "1007",
        "imagePaths" : [
                "1504422656691-Screenshot (4).png"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59abab004783d90bccb4a724"),
        "productId" : "1007",
        "imagePaths" : [
                "1504422656691-Screenshot (3).png"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

**

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `forEach`, you are creating new record for every file with `new Image`, rather what you should be doing is create an array of all the filename and make the record once. Maybe this piece of code will help you.

```
router.post('/upload', upload.any(), function(req , res){
  console.log('Executing Upload API..');
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);
  var images = req.files;

  const filePromises = req.files.map(function(file){
    var filename = (new Date()).valueOf() + '-' + file.originalname;
    console.log('FileName :' + filename);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      fs.rename(file.path,'public/images/'+ filename, function(err) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(filename);
      });
    });

  });

  Promise.all(filePromises)
  .then( fileNames => {

    var image = new Image({
      productId: 1007,
      imagePaths: fileNames
    });

    image.save(function(err, result){
      if(err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
  })

});
```

In this I have created the array of promises which will contain filename, and then resolving all of them using `Promise.all` to finally get the resolved array of filename, which then I can simply pass to create a new record.

Comment: Thanks, it's working as expected.

Comment: How can I display uploaded images using `angular js`?

Comment: I am not much familiar with angular. But since you are saving images in the public folder, you can just use the public folder path in img src.

Comment: okay, thanks, I will try that.